# Android issues with string comparison

Tags: android, json

I think I'm working too late and losing it but the string comparison in Android doesn't seem to work, probably it is just late.

I have a simple array of JSON objects and when my `auto` value is set to "0", I can compare that value to a `String`, when the `auto` is set to "1" the comparison goes straight into `Exception`?

I tried `equals` and `compareTo` with the same result. Are there other ways of comparing string on android that is more appropriate?

Thank you

```
private int findAutoPlayIndex(JSONArray items){
    try{
        int returnValue = -1;
        final int size = items.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            JSONObject jObjectResult = items.getJSONObject(i);

            String auto = items.getJSONObject(i).getString("auto").trim();

            //if ( auto.equals("1") ){
            //    return i;
            //}

            if ( auto.compareTo("1") == 0){
                return i;
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return  -1;
    }
}
```

[image]

Strange no stack ... nothing, IDE steps into that code but I can't see an exception variable or a stack

[image]

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: show the exception as well.

Comment: I tried all the solutions without luck that must be something else. I'm seeing some strange behavior in the IDE. When stepping through I jump to exception but I have not stack only a message that my e (Exception variable is missing) posting extra image in the original post.

Comment: @Radek inside that Exception block print/Log the value e

Comment: and `JSONObject jObjectResult = items.getJSONObject(i);

            String auto = items.getJSONObject(i).getString("auto").trim();` here you can simply write the second line as `String auto = jObjectResult.getString("auto").trim();`

Comment: If you followed what i said and still you have your issue its not with your compareTo or equals method its with your json parsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ("1".equals(auto)) {
    return i;
}
```

This will also handle null pointer exception in case `auto` has no value or if its null.

Comment: That was a really good idea, unfortunately didn't work for me :(  Must have to do something with JSON objects still looking

Answer (score 4):

try this one

```
if(Integer.parseInt(auto) == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`compareTo` method is described as follows:

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a
>   negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

**Note** that *null* is not an instance of any class, and `null.compareTo("1")` should throw a `Null Object Refference` even though `null.equals("1")`  [if you get a null for auto it will crash]

> int java.lang.String.compareTo(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

so 0 `compareTo` 1 will return you -1 meaning obj is less than to 1

But make sure you don't get a *null* value to `auto`

To make sure what you get check inside your conditions like the example if its android use Logs

```
String auto = "1";
if(auto == null){
        System.out.println("MyOutPut-> is null");
    }
    else if ( auto.compareTo("1") == 0){
        System.out.println("MyOutPut->"+auto.compareTo("1"));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("MyOutPut->" + auto.compareTo("1"));
    }
```

**warning** : Also for the Exception you are returning (-1 ).

But remember as i said compare to can rerun negative int. So -1 is possible. You might think it as an error because you return -1 when there's an exception but it might be the real value that you get from `compareTo` funtion.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if (auto.toString().equals("1")){
    return i;
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: why you perform stringValue.toString()?

Comment: because "auto" variable is a String type so comparing it using .equals() method there are other ways as well of comparing but i use this so i posted that  and its a working code that i posted.Doesn't matter i got up vote or not.

Comment: Its about learning not voting if you dont want that's fine :)

Comment: yes i agree but i don't deny that there aren't other ways of doing this task .Its just i had done before like this so i shared it. I am just saying that if it is right then only i should get up vote.Thats all i have to say

Comment: what your saying is like this `auto.toString().toString().toString().toString();` i used this and its working! of course it does but what's the point ?

Comment: please see my answer and then point out. And by the way toString() is only one time not multiple times in my code.

Comment: auto is already a string and you use toString()  ?? hope you learn something :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was totally silly. When stepping in debug mode in IDE, in my if equals logic I just had a one statement that is return i.

The comparison was working OK the IDE automatically skips next step to the last return statement in the function which in my case was in the exception handler.

That was why I didn't see an actual exception variable. You learn something new every day. Thank you for all your help.